# Ошибка при вызове дженерик класса

Tags: c#, nunit

Есть статический класс с дженериком

```
public static class Validations<T> where T: class
{
    private static AnketaContext context = new AnketaContext();

    public static bool CanUserStartTest(string TestableCode, Filials UserFilial, ref string accessName, ref string message)
    {      
        //Тут проходит первоначальная проверка валидности и выкидывается результат в случае ошибки
        
        //Этот результат выдаётся, если все предыдущие проверки прошли успешно
        return CheckAccessForTestable(TestableCode, ref accessName, ref message);
    }

    private static bool CheckAccessForTestable(string code, ref string accessName, ref string errors)
    {
        //TODO
        switch (typeof(T).Name)
        {
            case "Test360": //TODO
            case "MotivationTest"://TODO
            default://TODO
        }
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь протестировать метод этого класса

```
var result = Validations<Test360>.CanUserStartTest(TestableCode, filial, ref accessName, ref message);
Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedResult, result);
Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedErrMessage, message);
Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedAccessName, accessName);
```

Класс `Validations<Test360>` подчёркивается красным и выводится ошибка

> Неуниверсальный тип "Validations<Test360>" нельзя использовать с аргументами типа

Вроде всё делал по гайдам, и сам дженерик класс построил более менее верно. Но почему-то использовать его не получается.

Comment: Покажите реализацию метода CanUserStartTest или хотя бы его сигнатуру

Comment: @PavelPopov выложил полную реализацию класса. `T` используется только в методе `CheckAccessForTestable` для определения какой тест проходит юзер.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, что ругается на Validations, а именно на то что этот класс не дженерик. Возможно стоит убедится в том что класс действительно дженерик(возможно дженериком является метод этого класса), или возможно дженерик реализация класса имеет модификатор доступа internal или еще какой то, который не доступен в той сборке, в которой тестируется.

Upd:

Судя по коду, Вы делаете все правильно. Но есть еще один момент который стоит проверить. Возможно в Вашем проекте или какой то библиотеке, от которой зависит Ваш проект, есть класс с таким же наименованием, который не является generic'ом. Что бы это проверить попробуйте указать полное имя класса Validations (т.е. с пространством имен). Возможно Вы не добавили using того пространства имен в котором определен Generic класс Validations. Так же в Visual Studio можно быстро перейти к определению типа, просто установите курсор на Validations<...> и нажмите F12, или в контекстном меню нажмите "Go To Definition", если эти действия привели Вас не к Вашему Generic классу Validation, значит просто нужно указать нужный тип.

Comment: Написал полную реализацию класса. Возможно, так лучше будет видно, что не так. Но тип `T` мне нужен только в методе `CheckAccessForTestable` для определения какой тест проходит юзер.